# Problems retrieving data from [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

I'm developing a website with Node.Js, Express, EJS and MongoDB and I'm trying to pass the data sent by the server to a jquery script. I let here the esential parts:

**app.js**

```
  app.route('/SO/modificar')
    .get(function (req, res) {
      db.collection('SO').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
      res.render('admin/modSO.ejs', {so: result});
      }
    )
    })
```

**modSO.ejs**

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover overflow-auto">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                <th scope="col">Descripción</th>
                                <th scope="col">Arquitectura</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <% var cont=1; %>
                                <% so.forEach(function(details){ %>

                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">
                                            <%= cont %>
                                        </th>
                                        <td>
                                            <%= details._id %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%= details.name %>
                                        </td>
                                        <% if(details.description.length> 100){ %>
                                            <td>
                                                <%= details.description.substring(0, 100) %>...
                                            </td>
                                            <%}else{ %>
                                                <td>
                                                    <%= details.description %>
                                                </td>
                                                <% } %>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <table class="table overflow-auto">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <% var labels=details.labels %>
                                                                    <% for (let key in labels) { if(labels[key]){%>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            <td>
                                                                                <%= key %>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        <% }} %>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <% cont=cont + 1;}) %>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("tr").click(function () {
                let so = '<%-so%>'
                console.log(so);
               
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I just basically need to replace some input values with values contained in the "so" object. I have to say that **I already tried other way to access the data, which is getting it directly from the rendered table, but I need some data that is not shown there, so please don't propose a solution like that**

The problem is that console.log(so) displays this:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I have tried with some solutions proposed in other posts, like:

```
JSON.stringify(so), alert(so), <%=so%>
```

and still it returns the same message or nothing. Also I have tried with:

```
for (key in so) {
                    if (so.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        console.log(so[key])
                    }
                }
```

and it returns this:

```
[ 
o 
b 
j 
e 
c 
t 
 
O 
b 
j 
e 
c 
t 
] 
, 
[
```

I guess that JSON.stringify is not working for some type issue but I have no idea of what to do. Hope you can lend me a hand. Thanks to you all

Comment: Can you check if your app.js is really returning  what you think? (the `so: result` part)

Comment: Did you try so.get()

Comment: @MarcDix the app is returning the data correctly, It shows the content in the table. The problem is the jquery script.